# MacBook Air Screen Blank with Stripes

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

There are other questions about the screen being blank but this one has stripes. All started when I was  doing a 3D Virtual Tour. I did others before by the way. Then I took a photo and it said click to download. I kinda got excited and clicked too many times and when Safari made the prompt to allow the site I allowed it and then the file which was 1.3 MBs was being downloaded A LOT of times. The downloada was showing 2, the Safari Downloads was showing like 10 but there were a lot more icona coming from safari and jumping into the dowbloads folder in my mac, then the scrren suddenly became this stripy screen and I shut it down from the power button. I never had the chance to check top or Activity Monitor by the way but I think this may be enough.
Old Mac - 9 Years
MACBOOK AIR MID 2012 MACOS CATALINA 15.7
Please help it may be old but it was running fine.
On the phone so please forgive apelling and grammar or some other.
Edit:
[image: Photo of The Computer Screen]

Edit2:
I found out that only the screen is malfunctioning. I kinda logged in with my keyboard and even if it is only stripes i can see thing, my cursor is a long line and my mouse is: also a long line. I can see the movement as i touch my trackpad. The thing is the screen not the connection didn't get physical damage. I don't know by the way don't get it wrong the computer is still kinda unusable, it can't diaplay any text visually, it actually only displays cold desaturated blue stripes, no pixels.
Edit3:
I can adjust screen brightness.

Comment: Try an external monitor.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't log in to StackExchange for like 3 weeks. Actually, I already tried that as soon as my Thunderbolt to HDML came. Like 20 days go but thanks for the advice anyways. The external monitor works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not software, the download issue you describe is not related and is merely coincidental. That is definitely a hardware fault. I would recommend a 3rd party repair shop local to you as it's too old to bring to Apple.

It's usually the flex cable that connects the display to the system board beneath the keyboard.  Or the display panel itself is damaged. You can try very gently pressing with light pressure using your finger near the bottom of the screen and see if the image changes. That might indicate the panel itself is damaged.